# Using Int13h with FreeDos Debug

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, interrupt, bios

I'm working on some assembly, and as part of a school project I am using Int 13h 08 to Read current disk parameters, but I'm messing something up. I'm using FreeDOS in a VirtualBox, and using Debug.

My code is:

```
MOV AH,08
MOV DL,80
INT 13
MOV AH,4C
INT 21
```

Regardless of the termination part, nothing is being returned/printed than I'm aware of. 
Do I need to come up with some type of print code? I'm also not sure where any information that is read by this command would go to,

My thought process is that one of the registers would hold a pointer after the code is executed, and I just need to start reading from that pointer to see the information. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need any help on interrupts [Ralf Browns Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm) is your friend. (And yes, you have to come up with some printing code on your own, if you want to display the informations on screen).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample session of using your code in lDebug (a fork of FreeDOS Debug). I'm stepping through the code until after the interrupt 13h has been called.

```
-a
18BD:0100 mov ah, 8
18BD:0102 mov dl, 80
18BD:0104 int 13
18BD:0106
-r
AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=0000 DX=0000 SP=FFFE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=18BD ES=18BD SS=18BD CS=18BD IP=0100 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
18BD:0100 B408              mov     ah, 08
-t
AX=0800 BX=0000 CX=0000 DX=0000 SP=FFFE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=18BD ES=18BD SS=18BD CS=18BD IP=0102 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
18BD:0102 B280              mov     dl, 80
-
AX=0800 BX=0000 CX=0000 DX=0080 SP=FFFE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=18BD ES=18BD SS=18BD CS=18BD IP=0104 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
18BD:0104 CD13              int     13
-
AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=FE3F DX=FE04 SP=FFFE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=18BD ES=18BD SS=18BD CS=18BD IP=0106 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
18BD:0106 0000              add     [bx+si], al                      DS:0000=CD
-
```

At this point you can use the interrupt list entry linked by the other answer to determine what the results in the registers mean: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm